# Can I use a foreign power cord to power my MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, internationalization, power

I have a MacBook Pro computer and I will be traveling abroad to Hong Kong for studies. The electric sockets and voltage are different than here in the US so I would have to use a converter but it is a big hassle carrying around a power converter everywhere I go... I'm hoping to find another solution. If I purchase a HK MacBook Pro power cord will it work with my computer which I purchased in the US?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the MagSafe power adapters support dual voltage (100-240V).

According to the specs on Amazon for the [85W version](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000U3JR8S):

> Input: AC 100V~240V 50/60Hz

So long as the local input provides power in that range, you'll be able to get a local MagSafe compatible cord and your US MBP will be fine.